# Authenticating with SharePoint 2013 from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, sharepoint

I have a command-line script written in JavaScript which needs to connect to a REST Api on a remote SharePoint site, but I cannot figure out how to authenticate. I can log on in a browser using forms authentication, and by inspecting the request I should be able to reproduce it in node.js to get the appropriate auth cookie or token.  However, I actually get a 403 Forbidden.  I don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but I can't find very much info on it.  Here is my script:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$signInControl$UserName': 'restapi',
  'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$signInControl$password': 'my_password',
  'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$signInControl$login': 'Sign In'
});

var options = {
  hostname: 'sharepoint.example.com',
  port: 80,

  path: '/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ', res.headers);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

And the response headers are:

```
{ 'cache-control': 'private',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
  'x-sharepointhealthscore': '0',
  'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
  sprequestguid: '366d149d-79af-b07c-1764-dec7001b46a2',
  'request-id': '366d149d-79af-b07c-1764-dec7001b46a2',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  sprequestduration: '7',
  spiislatency: '0',
  'x-forms_based_auth_required': 'http://sharepoint.example.com/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F',
  'x-forms_based_auth_return_url': 'http://sharepoint.example.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx',
  'x-msdavext_error': '917656; Access denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.',
  'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
  microsoftsharepointteamservices: '15.0.0.4569',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-ms-invokeapp': '1; RequireReadOnly',
  date: 'Sat, 27 Jun 2015 10:53:28 GMT',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '13' }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that REST API allows CORS? because a 403 Forbidden might mean that you are not allowed to contact that endpoint from outside.

Does that remote SharePoint app use AD for authentication?
if so you might need to check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory